# Server showing 89% occupied after installation

Tags: installation

I have a server of 250MB disk space and MYSQL of 115 MB. And I have just installed basic Drupal 8 site and it's showing me 208 MB and 75 MB(MYSQL) occupied. What can I do? I don't want to upgrade my server at this point in time.

Answer (score 1):

~200MB is about the size of Drupal 8 with the composer dependencies installed (which cannot be removed without breaking the site).

If you want to try Drupal 8 without paying for a more expensive server, you can use a preconfigured local development environment like [Acquia Dev Desktop](https://www.acquia.com/products-services/dev-desktop) or [lando](https://github.com/lando/lando).  This puts the server on your computer for testing purposes, which should run pretty well but may be a bit slow on a low-powered laptop.

You could also sign up for a free dev account with [Pantheon](https://pantheon.io), which allows you to do development on their server instead of setting up a server on your own machine, but it may be a little tricky to move your site to another host later because Pantheon uses nginx and many other hosts are using apache for Drupal.

Comment: Amazon AWS or Lightsail is also a solution for hosting.

Comment: @Kevin This is not about hosting this is about testing Drupal in a simple way for free. Hosting recommendations are OT for this site because it would result in lots of spam.